# Error while trying to unrar

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell

> unrar: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Both rar & unrar are in the /bin folder

I followed this tutorial: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/open-rar-file-or-extract-rar-files-under-linux-or-unix/

Comment: What distribution are you using? is libgcc installed?

Comment: Which distro are you using and did you install via the package manager or the tarball?  (Those are both possible options when following the link you provided.)

Comment: I installed it manually as AWS EC2 didn't have the package I was looking for. And I tried reinstalling / installing libgcc both time prior and now resulted in the same error however I'm not very linux savvy so I may have done something wrng

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, I bet you are running on a 64-bit Linux installation, and you have a 32-bit version of your rar utility.  If you are on a Red Hat / Fedora distro, you can `yum install libgcc.i686` to install the 32-bit libgcc version.  32-bit libraries go under /lib and /usr/lib, whereas 64-bit ones are under /lib64 and /usr/lib64.